# Looking for ICs; can I ask here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, on-topic

I am looking for an IC with a very specific set of requirements; can I ask about it here?

Technically it's a product recommendation question and, while I don't know this site well, I'm just assuming it's got a similar policy to other SE sites (i.e.: nope).

However, assuming that's the case, I feel like there *might* be some compelling cases for making exceptions specifically in the case of integrated circuits? Specifically:

- Unlike most product rec questions, this might not be as opinion-base because there tend to only be one or two manufacturers that make a given highly specialized IC, so an answer would often be *the* answer.
- The product lifetimes (and post-EOL supply stores) tend to be long enough that it's not e.g. getting obsoleted every couple of months, and even if it does go out of production (and supply disappears), searching for a part given in an old answer usually yields its replacement. So answers shouldn't depreciate in value as quickly as typical product recs.
- The products are generally specialized enough that I would expect other people's Google searches to end up pointing here, usually in the first few results, thus adding value to the internet.
- It's a knowledgeable community that can provide good answers often based on experience.

Anyways, can I ask about an IC here? What do y'all think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can phrase it as a design question it's acceptable.
I personally find the restriction on asking genuine design questions which have good technical content and instructional value to be an excessive limitation on what could be useful questions. The aim is to avoid generic "where can I buy an xxx" type questions but in the process I consider we drive away a substantial amount of useful material.

However, my concerns do not alter what the rules are :-) :-(.

If you cannot reframe the question adequately for this site then you will almost get a good answer from the following forum that supports discussion  - I suggest that you look at http://www.piclist.com (don't be put off by the presentation or the PIC in the name). Then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist and join the mailing list & say hello. Provide as much detail of your requirements and problems as possible.

Just like here, there are people there who know almost everything (collectively), and you are allowed to discuss anything conversationally. Some members of this group are also PICList members (myself included). It's a very useful complement to this site for questions of this sort.

Comment: No kidding.   Sometimes just knowing what ICs to use is 50% of the design exercise.

Comment: @Leroy105 Indeed. While my answer may sound obvious it needed stating as it is not how this site works.

Answer (score 5):

Asking for product recommendations is off topic (for all of SE). If you need to ask these types of questions, the chat feature will be the best way, but YMMV.

https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/